# Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException in dotnet program

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have recently taken over a project and am trying to start the dotnet backend server on my mac. I keep getting the error you see below in the Program.cs file when i run the application.

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException
An unhandled exception of type 'Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll: 'DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Operating system Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:17:10 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_X86_64 isn't supported.
- VisualStudioCodeCredential authentication unavailable. Token acquisition failed. Ensure that you have authenticated in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot
- Please run 'az login' to set up account
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException : EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.<GetTokenAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.<GetTokenFromSourcesAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

The application uses azure keyvault for enviroment variables.

What i tried:

1. Asked for my azure user to be invited to the project.
2. My azure account has been granted owner rights.
3. Installed azure cli and used az login on vs code.
4. Added data reader rights on the key vault access control.
5. Added my user to access policies with the same permissions as the dev before me.

I also sure to log in on the azure account in visual studio code before i ran program. Also tried in regular visual studio for mac os, but had the same result.

Comment: Check the access keys from your configuration... maybe they are missing or are not available anymore or the project needs an application object that u should define.

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this issue with the same error message. I could either call `az login`prior to running the program

or I could call `DefaultAzureCredential` with the parameter `includeInteractiveCredentials:true`

```cs
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true));
```

this opens a browser and tries to login the current user and enables the login.

source: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Identity/1.4.1/index.html#enabling-the-interactive-authentication-with-the-defaultazurecredential

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the tenant you logged in is correct.
In order to verify the account which is currently logged in to the Azure CLI.
Use  `Get-AzContext`

[image]

- From there check if the correct tenantId or tenant is in use .
- If not login with correct credentials through required credentials
  property.
- Exclude all credential options  other than the one which is needed.
- Exclude the credential with the ExcludeXXXCredential property in the
  `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions`.

example:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{
ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = false,
ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
ExcludeAzureCliCredential = false,
ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential=true});
```

> Please note that the DefaultAzureCredential and EnvironmentCredential
> can be able to configured  with environment variables which requires
> specific variables:

- Default credentials looks for  local values, so if they are not
  present, then it will take from ManagedIdentityCredential,
  SharedTokenCacheCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential .(*Exclude
  what is not needed explicitly* .)
- Please make sure environment variables has
  AZURE_CLIENT_ID,AZURE_TENANT_ID,AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET  when  using
  secret.

**Reference** : [Environment variables · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables)